# Design Pattern for different data

Tags: design-patterns

I have a repository class the Entity that I work with has a IsHistorical flag.  There is a FindWhere method in this repository for which I will need three versions.

> One version will be the case when I want to return rows matching the
>   condition that are historical
>
> The second version will be the case when I want to return rows
>   matching the condition that are not historical
>
> And the third version will be the case when I want to return rows
>   matching the condition regardless of whether it is historical or not

Instead of having three methods and later on three sets of other methods, surely there must be a clever design pattern out there that deals with this elegantly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would go for simplicity and prefer 3 methods. You can certainly pass around some AbstractFactory but simplicity would pay up down the line.

Comment: pass an additional enum argument to the methods: HISTORICAL, NON_HISTORICAL, BOTH?

Comment: Probably you are looking for something like the Interpreter Pattern.